# How do you change the camera focal length in Blender 2.8?

Tags: camera

In Blender 2.79 this option was in the Camera tab.  In 2.8 I see I can adjust the 3D viewport focal length.  However when I go into camera view, I can't seem to find a place to adjust the camera focal length.  Is this done differently in 2.8?

Comment: You can still toggle the N menu and toggle from item to view on the right side.

Comment: I've made a tuto to show a to create a shortcurt to create interactive Focal: don't hesitate to shareif you find it usefull:) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8lnYfU5lw0&t=21s Best

Answer (score 7):

You can change the lens settings on the properties window. Select the camera, look for the camera options and in the lens section you can set the focal length.

[image]

Or you can also set it visually by clicking on the camera and dragging while holding the control key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I can change the focal length first in Eevee then switch back to cycles.  Not sure if there's an option to do this when in Cycles.

Comment: Are you using the last build ? A similar bug has been reported and corrected really recently (Feb 13)